# CAA tag not appearing as suggested tag

Tags: support, bug, tags

When starting to type the caa tag "caa-uk-regulations", if you just type "caa" then a load of random suggested tags that only contain "ca" appears.

[image: Screenshot of caa tags]

It isn't until you put "caa-" the appropriate tag appears.

[image: Screenshot of caa- tags]

The suggested tags in the first screenshot are clearly not the most appropriate so can the caa tag be made to appear when only "caa" is typed in to help people find it easier?

**Edit**
Appears to be specific to Safari on iOS 10 using the full website (not mobile website).

Comment: Safari, full website on iOS. I tested it in the iOS app and it work correctly too. Must be just that browser.

Comment: latest FF on Win, no problem here.

Comment: Unable to reproduce on IE 10.

Comment: Looks fine on desktop browsers; hunting down my ipad to check on iOS...